# Automatically redirect to another page when link is entered in input box

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, input, paste

I am creating a simple web page that will allow the user to paste a web url link into an input box. Once they have pasted it in then the page will automatically send them to that specific page.

I don't need a button, just a way for them to paste and then the page loads the url they have pasted.

```
<template>
    <div class="importEvent">
        <img class="imageSize" src="~/assets/Missing Icons/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook">
        <InputComponent placeholder="Paste your facebook event here" v-model="facebookPaste" class="inputFacebook"></InputComponent>

        <div class="manualOption">
            or <nuxt-link to="/create-event" class="manualLink">create manually</nuxt-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

If someone can please help, it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please create HTML/CSS at least. People will help you and guide you to write logic. :)

Comment: @KalpeshSingh I have just added my HTML to the question

Comment: You should tell your users to paste the URL in the address bar of their browser.

Comment: @ceving : Like your comment same thought in my mind

Comment: @Seblor I haven't tried much, I have just been researching but I can't find anything that is helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make this work.

I changed the `<InputComponent>` tag I had to a normal `<input>` tag and then added an `@change` which would link to a method I created.

Below is what I did.

```
<input placeholder="Paste your facebook event here" v-model="facebookPaste" @change="pastedUrl()" class="inputFacebook" onkeypress="return false;">

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            facebookPaste: ''
        }
    },

    methods: {
        pastedUrl: function(){
            location.replace(this.facebookPaste)
        }
    }
}
```

`onkeypress="return false;"`: allows me to only paste and not type anything which is what I wanted as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think your questions a litil bit awkward well you can set internal and check regularly value of input box when input box get some value  redirect to another page

```
 var input_text="";
 var time=setInterval(function(){
     input_text=document.getElementsByTagName("InputComponent")[0].getAttribute("value");
          if(input_text.length>0)
          {
           //redirect code goes here
          clearInterval(time);
          },500);
```

here i assume that your element index is 0;
it can be done the keybord eventListner also but there might be some problem if input gose with the help of mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your `InputComponent`, but if use `<input>` you can try this code:

```
<template>
    <div class="importEvent">
        <img class="imageSize" src="~/assets/Missing Icons/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Paste your facebook event here" class="inputFacebook" @paste="pasteLink($event)"/>

        <div class="manualOption">
            or <nuxt-link to="/create-event" class="manualLink">create manually</nuxt-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    pasteLink: function(evt) {
      const url = evt.clipboardData.getData("text") || "";
      // you can check url by regexp
      location.href = url; // go away to url
    }
}
</script>
```

That code is just for your requirements - after paste url. Not when write text in input, but just after paste.
Hope this help you.